# Restructuring a large amount of values in a JSON file

Tags: json, text, replace, formatting, format

I have a JSON file with a large amount of the following values:

```
"values": [
      "Foo": 1,
      "Bar": 2,
      "Baz": 3,
      ...
  ],
```

How do I efficiently convert this into:

```
"values": [
    {
      "name": "Foo",
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Bar",
      "value": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "Baz",
      "value": 3
    },
      ...
  ],
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so there are two problems with your input. The first is the fact that the given JSON is invalid, so can't directly be parsed. The square brackets after `"values"` should be curly brackets, to allow for a hash instead of an array:

```
let raw_old_data =
    // Read the old file
    fs.readFileSync('./input_data.json').toString()

    // Remove all newlines which could interfere with the regex
    .replace(/[\r\n]/g, '')

    // Replace the square brackets after `"values"` with curly braces
    .replace(/"values": \[(.+?)\]/g, '"values": { $1 }');
```

To convert this (now valid) string to a JSON object, you use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
let old_data = JSON.parse(raw_old_data);
```

The second problem is that the format in which the values are stored doesn't match your needs. You want to convert from `{ key: "value" }` to `[ name: "key", value: "value" ]`. The following function can do that, assuming your version of Node supports ES6 (If not, look at Murillo's answer):

```
function fix_format(obj) {
    // This is where we keep the new items in the correct format
    let res = [];

    // Loop over all values
    Object.keys(obj.values).forEach(name => {
        let value = obj.values[name];

        // Change the format and add to resulting array
        res.push({
            // If the variable is the same as the key of the hash, it doesn't have to be specified
            name,
            value,
        });
    });


    return res;
}
```

All that's then left to do is loop all data from the old object through that function with the [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```
let new_data = old_data.map(fix_format);
```

And optionally write it back to a file to use with a different program:

```
fs.writeFileSync('./formatted_data.json', JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
```

**Note**: The `2` in the [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function indicates that the resulting JSON should be padded with 2 spaces, to keep it readable.

Answer (score 0):

With ES6:

```
Object.keys(values).map(name => ({
    name,
    value: values[name]
}))
```

Without ES6:

```
var keys = Object.keys(values);
var newValues = [];

for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
    newValues.push({
        name: keys[i],
        value: values[keys[i]]
    })
}
```

Comment: could you explain what ES6 is exactly?

Comment: ES6 is a major update to JavaScript that includes dozens of new features that you can see in this link: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_es6.asp

Comment: oh but i don't use javascript for my project, i was actually looking for a tool to sort of find and replace the parts i need

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to use the received data i.e obtain data from DB (e.g MSSql, MySql...)
 using the `connection.query(your_custom_sql_query, (err, rows, fields)`

for more info:
[Node.js MySQL Select From Table](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_select.asp)
I'll recommend you to use:
`const myJson = JSON.stringify(rows[0]);`